# List all non-admin enqueued files

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I am using `$wp_scripts` and `$wp_styles` in my admin area to get a list of all css and js files on my site, but only admin registered styles and scripts are being added, I have googled and can't find a way to grab the "frontend" css/js rather than the admin.

My code so far:

```
global $wp_scripts;
foreach( $wp_scripts->queue as $handle ) :
 echo $handle;
endforeach;
```

Anyone have an ideas of how to achieve this?

Comment: I don't think you can get front end scripts and styles from an admin request, because they're added on hooks that aren't triggered on the admin side.

Comment: Why? Maybe there is an approach that would work if we know why you were trying to do this.

Comment: It was an idea for a plugin, but after lots of searching what I want to do isn't possible, I would need to do it on the front end so scrapped the idea, but thanks for the inputs